# Counting files that start with the same characters

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I'm trying to get a count of all files in a directory whose first few characters match a string.  Here is the function:

```
function CountMatchingID($d1,$s){
    $d = Get-ChildItem -filter $s -path $d1 | Measure-Object
    return $d.count 
}
```

I'm passing in the directory and a variable with a wildcard.  It is returning the total count of files in the directory.  However if I change the `$s` inside the function to the value of that variable like below, it will return the accurate number of files that have that beginning.

```
function CountMatchingID($d1,$s){
    $d = Get-ChildItem -filter "201*" -path $d1 | Measure-Object
    return $d.count 
}
```

The files are employee id photos with employee numbers at the beginning and I'm trying to automate searching a csv file to rename them to the username so we can dump them into a directory for Jabber to show the photos.

I'm open to suggestions about a better way to accomplish this as well.  I'm fairly new to Powershell so any feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue might be what you are passing as `$s` for which you don't show an example. This works as expected for me

```
function CountMatchingID($d1,$s){
    Get-ChildItem -filter "$s*" -path $d1 | Measure-Object | Select -ExpandProperty Count
}
```

I added the asterisk into the filter automatically so that it can just be assumed.

A sample call would look like this

```
CountMatchingID "c:\temp" "test"
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, you gave me what I needed.  I was calling the function like so: `CountMatchingID($dir, $id)`

Comment: My theory was correct then. Your example is used for static methods not function calls. You would have been passing array to the first variable.